# Taking Real, Im, and Abs of polynomial fractions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex, polynomials

I want to find out real imaginary and Abs of polynomial fractions composed of real-valued variables.

For example, consider we have a  polynomial fraction
$f=\dfrac{a_1 +b_1 i }{a_2 +b_2 i }$ where $a_{1,2}$ and $b_{1,2}$ arereal valued variables (in fact, my actual values are again complecated fuctions of real-valued variables). (edit) Natual choice was to use inbuilt functions, but their output was as follows:
[image]

How can I simplify the real, imaginary, and using standard Mathematica function?

This is what I have so far, for example, for the Abs.

```
   Myabs[complex_] := Module[{Nreal, Nimag, Dreal, Dimag, real, imag},
   Nreal = Numerator[complex] /. Complex[a_, b_] -> a;
   Nimag = (Numerator[complex] - Nreal)/I;
   Dreal = Denominator[complex] /. Complex[a_, b_] -> a;
   Dimag = (Denominator[complex] - Dreal)/I;
   real = (Nreal  Dreal + Nimag  Dimag)/(Dreal^2 + Dimag^2);
   imag = (  Dreal Nimag -  Nreal Dimag)/(Dreal^2 + Dimag^2);
   Sqrt[real^2 + imag^2]];
```

This function does the job for me so far. But I feel that there should be a better and straightforward way to do it.

Comment: Would [`Re`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Re.html), `Im`, and `Abs` not work here? Can you give us an example where they fail but your function works, to see if maybe they can still be forced to work as you would like?

Comment: Thanks, @MarcoB.  Of course, that was what I first tried. But the output was not as expected. Just edited the question with a screen capture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

expr = (a1 + I*b1)/(a2 + I*b2);
```

[`ComplexExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html) will assume that all variables are real unless otherwise specified.

```
Abs[expr] // ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] &

(* Sqrt[a1^2 + b1^2]/Sqrt[a2^2 + b2^2] *)

Re[expr] // ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & // Simplify

(* (a1 a2 + b1 b2)/(a2^2 + b2^2) *)

Im[expr] // ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & // Simplify

(* (a2 b1 - a1 b2)/(a2^2 + b2^2) *)
```

Comment: Perfect! It is the masterpiece I was looking for. What is really happening with Clear["Global`*"]? (just to get better understanding)

Comment: `Clear["Global\`*"]` ensures that any prior definitions that might conflict are removed.

Comment: Got it! I should have asked this question long before! Thanks.